# VBA - Erro de definição de aplicativo ou de definição de objeto

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6, excel-vba

Estou tentando recuperar a quantidade de linhas de uma planilha excel para formata-la, porém estou me deparando com o erro de definição de aplicativo ou de definição de objeto. Segue abaixo o trecho de código.

```
Private Function formataPlanilha(pathWorkbook As String, dic As Object)

objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' ABRE ARQUIVO
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(pathWorkbook)
objExcel.Application.Visible = False

objExcel.Sheets.Add.Name = "TD"
objExcel.Sheets(dic("Sheet_Name")).Select

' INICIO DA FORMATAÇÃO
objExcel.Cells.Select
objExcel.Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objExcel.Selection.Font.Size = 9
objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
objExcel.Selection.RowHeight = 13.5
objExcel.Selection.AutoFilter

' RECUPERA QUANTIDADE DE LINHAS
objExcel.Range("A1").Select
objExcel.Selection.End(xlDown).Select
maxRows = objExcel.ActiveCell.Row
```

Acredito que o erro esteja ocorrendo em xlDown. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Bom é que para declarar uma Range, você deve nomear o workbook e worksheet para evitar alguns erros, caso o código esteja dentro da planilha Excel. Por exemplo: `Set ws = Sheets("Planilha1")`  e usar `ws.range("A1").Select`. Veja um exemplo de [como declarar](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-CreateObject-31917b05-1530-48f5-86d6-d2bd748aad74), pode ser a falta de declaração de qual livro deve ser aberto e qual planilha. Você está programando somente para a planilha Excel ou para interagir com outros softwares?

Comment: @danieltakeshi poste a resposta Daniel para que seja marcado como respondida.

Comment: @danieltakeshi, na verdade tenho consultas no access que geram minha planilha e um módulo responsável por exportar e formata-la. A planilha gerada não é vazia. Tenho o workbook e worksheet declarados. Vou editar a pergunta para melhor entendimento

Comment: É sempre bom evitar o uso de [Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) e usar Ranges, vou verificar a planilha melhor mais tarde e aviso aqui. E a declaração das variáveis? como é feita? `Dim ... As Object`?

Comment: Dim pathWorkbook As String
Dim dic As Object
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
pathWorkbook = path & fileName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu obtive o número correto de linhas com este código de teste, algumas alterações podem ser feitas para você utilizar. O código foi feito em Excel-VBA 7.1. Pelo que entendi a planilha já existe.

```
Dim objExcel As Object: Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim pathWorkbook As String: pathWorkbook = "C:\Users\nome_usuario\Desktop\Pasta1.xlsm"
Dim objWorkbook As Object: Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(pathWorkbook)
Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nomePlanilha As String
Dim maxRows As Long

objExcel.Visible = False

nomePlanilha = "Planilha1"
Set ws = objWorkbook.Sheets(nomePlanilha)
' INICIO DA FORMATAÇÃO
With ws
    objExcel.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    objExcel.Cells.Font.Size = 9
    objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    objExcel.Cells.RowHeight = 13.5
    objExcel.Cells.AutoFilter
End With

' RECUPERA QUANTIDADE DE LINHAS
maxRows = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print maxRows

On Error Resume Next
objWorkbook.Close (True)
On Error Goto 0
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
```

## PASSOS PARA DECLARAR CORRETAMENTE

1. Criar um objeto de Aplicação Excel `Dim objExcel As Object: Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`
2. Criar a String no nome do caminho do arquivo `Dim pathWorkbook As String: Let pathWorkbook = "Caminho"`
3. Abrir a planilha Excel `Dim objWorkbook As Object: Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(pathWorkbook)`
4. Declarar a planilha do Excel `Dim ws As Object` e selecionar o nome da mesma `Set ws = objWorkbook.Sheets(nomePlanilha)` pode ser o nome entre aspas ("Planilha1") ou o número de index (1,2,3,etc.)
5. Com a planilha ws declarada, você pode utilizá-la para realizar as operações em Excel-VBA
6. Para fechar corretamente `objWorkbook.Close (True)` True salva a planilha e False não salva.

### Nota

Para ver a janela do `Debug.Print`, habilite no Excel VBA a Verificação imediata.

Caso a planilha ainda não exista, então você precisa adicioná-la:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
With objWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "TD"
End With
```

## Edit:

O que você deve ter esquecido é de habilitar os objetos Excel nas referências.

**1o Abra o Visual Basic do Access**

**2o Entre em Ferramentas -> Referências...**

**3o Habilite o Microsoft Excel Object conforme a imagem abaixo:**

[image: Excel object reference]

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção. Estou enfrentando problemas com a declaração do Worksheet, informando erro de compilação, informando que o tipo definido pelo usuario não foi definido. Isso ocorre bem na linha Dim ws As Worksheet

Comment: Você está declarando dentro do Excel-VBA? E que versão, ano? Tente trocar para `Dim ws As Object`

Comment: Estou no Access-VBA, em um módulo. Uso a versão 7.1, 2012.

Comment: O código que eu tenho consegue efetuar a exportação e formatação normalmente, porém o mesmo se encontra na versão 2007 do access. Na 2016 não é possível

Comment: É, estava programando no Excel 2016, mas daí você disse Access, então alterei e funcionou. Vou editar a resposta. Próxima vez escolha as tags corretas e fale que a programação é feita no Access

Comment: Falha minha. Na semana que vem verificarei a resposta e ja marco como correta se me atender. Obrigado pela atenção, novamente