# Erro ao tentar abrir um arquivo Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, visual-basic-6, excel-vba, vbscript

Estou tentando abrir um documento no excel via vbScript. Não estou tendo sucesso na execução, ao executar é gerado o seguinte erro, sem descrição:

> -2147417851

O problema ocorre ao executar o seguinte comando:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")    
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open (Caminho)
```

*Observações:*

Estou tentando acessar um arquivo que esta na rede.

Comment: Leia [esta referência](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1ffe22e9-df8f-4208-9419-d5df9f203aaa/runtime-error-2147417851-80010105?forum=accessdev), em que está escrito que: **"** _Erros do tipo -2147417851 (80010105) são geralmente causados por não possuir permissão para abrir o arquivo._**"** . Se você testa este arquivo localmente, o código funciona? E que versão do excel está sendo utilizada?

Comment: E recentemente respondi uma [questão similar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/239760/75104), porém com outro erro. Caso este código não funcione localmente, verifique a resposta para entender como declarar corretamente e habilitar as referências.

Comment: Eu testei localmente e mesmo assim  ocorre o erro. A versão do excel é a 12.0 referente ao Office 2007